# Why can't I upload or create files to the Master Page Gallery on my sharepoint.com root site collect?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, custom-masterpage

In a sharepoint.com trial site, for my root site collection, I can't upload master pages (or anything else for that matter). I tried deleting the root site collection and re-creating it as a publishing site, but I keep getting the same error: Access denied.

I can access the Master Page Gallery just fine, and in the Files tab of the ribbon, choose either New Document or Upload Document. However as soon as I select something, I get "Sorry, you don't have access to this page". I have site collection admin, and am in the site owners group.

I have tried requesting permission, and granting myself full control. I also went to the library settings of the master page gallery library and tried from there. I also can't open the root site collection in SharePoint Designer, I get a 403 Forbidden response. I am able to do this on other non-root site collections, just not for the root site colleciton.

What gives?

Answer (score 6):

**SOLVED **
The problem is related to 'Scripting Capabilities' being turned off by default for the root site collection in Office 365.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-scripting-capabilities-on-or-off-1f2c515f-5d7e-448a-9fd7-835da935584f?ui=en-US&=amp&rs=en-US&ad=US

Although it mentions turning on scripting through the Sharepoint Admin Settings and waiting 24 hours, this did not work for me.

The Powershell script in same article did work, immediately :

```
 Set-SPOsite "SiteURL" -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0
```

Comment: This has worked for me also. You will need the O365 Management Shell also if not installed. It will need to be run as Administrator. https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=35588 Somewhat surprised issue has not been fixed!

Answer (score 0):

I was only able to solve this after filing a ticket with microsoft. Their solution was to delete my root site collection and then re-add it as a team site.

After that I was able to enable publishing features.